# Read .mat files in Python

Tags: python, matlab, file-io, scipy, mat-file

Is it possible to read binary MATLAB .mat files in Python?

I've seen that SciPy has alleged support for reading .mat files, but I'm unsuccessful with it. I installed SciPy version 0.7.0, and I can't find the `loadmat()` method.

Answer (score 786, accepted):

An import is required, `import scipy.io`...

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('file.mat')
```

Comment: scipy does not support v7.3 mat-files (see notes [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)). See the [answer by vikrantt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19340117/674976) for solution.

Comment: however, you can save mat-files as earlier versions. see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html (header: 'Save to Nondefault MAT-File Version')

Comment: e.g. `save('myfile.mat','-v7')`

Comment: Updated link to the SciPy.io tutorial https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/io.html @FranckDernoncourt

Answer (score 218):

Neither `scipy.io.savemat`, nor `scipy.io.loadmat` work for MATLAB arrays version 7.3. But the good part is that MATLAB version 7.3 files are hdf5 datasets. So they can be read using a number of tools, including [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy).

For Python, you will need the `h5py` extension, which requires HDF5 on your system.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('somefile.mat','r')
data = f.get('data/variable1')
data = np.array(data) # For converting to a NumPy array
```

Comment: This works fine, if you use the '-v7.3' flag in Matlab when saving out your data.  Using the default `save` (at least in Matlab R2014b) results in a file that cannot be read using the technique above.  If you do use the '-v7.3' flag, the numeric data can be read just fine.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my post. You need to use -v7.3 while saving in Matlab. You should do that anyways as it uses a better/more supported/standardized format.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the relation between _f_ and _data_ in your example? How can I move _f_ to a numpy array?

Comment: Save a variable with this command from the prompt: `save('filename', '-v7.3', 'var1');`

Comment: How would i even know that it contains data under data/variable1 ??

Comment: @devSpartan `f.keys()` will show you what you can access

Comment: "Unable to open file (file signature not found)"

Comment: @heracho f is the file object that lets you read data from the hdf5 file. It's similar to using `f = open('myfile.txt')` to read a text file.

Comment: @vikrantt This is a great solution for reading a `struct` but it does **not** work for a Matlab `table`. To read tables, you can't use the `save` function. Instead, you need to utilize the `h5create` and `h5write` functions.

Answer (score 33):

First save the .mat file as:

```
save('test.mat', '-v7')
```

After that, in Python, use the usual `loadmat` function:

```
import scipy.io as sio
test = sio.loadmat('test.mat')
```

Answer (score 27):

There is a nice package called [`mat4py`](https://pypi.org/project/mat4py/) which can easily be installed using

```
pip install mat4py
```

It is straightforward to use (from the website):

**Load data from a MAT-file**

The function `loadmat` loads all variables stored in the MAT-file into a simple Python data structure, using only Python’s `dict` and `list` objects. Numeric and cell arrays are converted to row-ordered nested lists. Arrays are squeezed to eliminate arrays with only one element. The resulting data structure is composed of simple types that are compatible with the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.

Example: Load a MAT-file into a Python data structure:

```
from mat4py import loadmat

data = loadmat('datafile.mat')
```

The variable `data` is a `dict` with the variables and values contained in the MAT-file.

**Save a Python data structure to a MAT-file**

Python data can be saved to a MAT-file, with the function `savemat`. Data has to be structured in the same way as for `loadmat`, i.e. it should be composed of simple data types, like `dict`, `list`, `str`, `int`, and `float`.

Example: Save a Python data structure to a MAT-file:

```
from mat4py import savemat

savemat('datafile.mat', data)
```

The parameter `data` shall be a `dict` with the variables.

Comment: Note that mat4py gives you a json-like tree of dicts, lists, lists of lists ... -- no numpy at all. (`mat4py/cmd.py my.mat` writes `my.json`, 1 long line.)

Comment: @denis: Yes, that's also stated above. But a good point indeed: I usually like this structure, e.g. in web applications as [numpy arrays are not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable).

Comment: Encountered: `mat4py.loadmat.ParseError: Can only read from Matlab level 5 MAT-files`

Comment: @s2t2: never ran into this issue before. What matlab version and which scipy version are you using?

Comment: ParseError: Unexpected field name length: 43

Comment: @AleksejsFomins: Probably best to open a new question and link to this thread; then it will be easier to help (make sure to provide all info needed to reproduce the error).

Comment: @s2t2 mat4py cannot read the new matlab format from version 7.3, which is encoded as hdf5.

Comment: Also note that mat4py does not allow to read complex valued .mat files

Comment: I faced this issue: "mat4py.loadmat.ParseError: Can only read from Matlab level 5 MAT-files"

Comment: good solution for fallback if scipy is not available (for example on Rasperry Pi). its also faster with pure number data but slower if there are strings

Answer (score 17):

Having MATLAB 2014b or newer installed, the [MATLAB engine for Python](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) could be used:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
content = eng.load("example.mat", nargout=1)
```

Comment: I got this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylab'.

Comment: You got the error when trying this answers? That is odd, it does not use pylab.

Comment: For the record, this answer requires a valid Matlab installation and license - it runs Matlab in the background to accomplish the read. And there may be limitations on what format you get the items in that need further work to make them readable. For example, Simulink.Bus objects come in as a "matlab object" and must be processed further, with issues if you want to extract the Bus Element objects.

Answer (score 17):

There is a great library for this task called: `pymatreader`.

Just do as follows:

1. Install the package: `pip install pymatreader`
2. Import the relevant function of this package: `from pymatreader import read_mat`
3. Use the function to read the matlab struct: `data = read_mat('matlab_struct.mat')`
4. use `data.keys()` to locate where the data is actually stored.

- The keys will usually look like: `dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'data_opp'])`. Where `data_opp` will be the actual key which stores the data. The name of this key can ofcourse be changed between different files.

5. Last step - Create your dataframe: `my_df = pd.DataFrame(data['data_opp'])`

That's it :)

Comment: The 2 things that it did better are: it preserve the mat object dimension and the loaded object was in NumPy array. Thanks

Comment: This one worked out of the box very nicely for me too :) . All the other methods were failing to get the arrays in the right dimensions, and / or missing metadata, and / or were very boilerplate and verbose (the "open h5 file by hand" one).

Answer (score 15):

**Reading the file**

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(file_name)
```

**Inspecting the type of MAT variable**

```
print(type(mat))
#OUTPUT - <class 'dict'>
```

*The **keys** inside the dictionary are **MATLAB variables**, and the **values** are the **objects assigned to those variables**.*

Comment: I am getting the error "ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 9, 99". Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 11):

To read mat file to pandas dataFrame with mixed data types

```
import scipy.io as sio
mat=sio.loadmat('file.mat')# load mat-file
mdata = mat['myVar']  # variable in mat file 
ndata = {n: mdata[n][0,0] for n in mdata.dtype.names}
Columns = [n for n, v in ndata.items() if v.size == 1]
d=dict((c, ndata[c][0]) for c in Columns)
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 10):

There is also the [MATLAB Engine for Python](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) by MathWorks itself. If you have MATLAB, this might be worth considering (I haven't tried it myself but it has a lot more functionality than just reading MATLAB files). However, I don't know if it is allowed to distribute it to other users (it is probably not a problem if those persons have MATLAB. Otherwise, maybe NumPy is the right way to go?).

Also, if you want to do all the basics yourself, [MathWorks provides](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf) (if the link changes, try to google for `matfile_format.pdf` or its title `MAT-FILE Format`) a detailed documentation on the structure of the file format. It's not as complicated as I personally thought, but obviously, this is not the easiest way to go. It also depends on how many features of the `.mat`-files you want to support.

I've written a "small" (about 700 lines) Python script which can read some basic `.mat`-files. I'm neither a Python expert nor a beginner and it took me about two days to write it (using the MathWorks documentation linked above). I've learned a lot of new stuff and it was quite fun (most of the time). As I've written the Python script at work, I'm afraid I cannot publish it... But I can give some advice here:

- First read the documentation.
- Use a hex editor (such as [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)) and look into a reference `.mat`-file you want to parse.
- Try to figure out the meaning of each byte by saving the bytes to a .txt file and annotate each line.
- Use classes to save each data element (such as `miCOMPRESSED`, `miMATRIX`, `mxDOUBLE`, or `miINT32`)
- The `.mat`-files' structure is optimal for saving the data elements in a tree data structure; each node has one class and subnodes

Comment: That's a somehow crazy documentation provided by mathworks. 40 pages explaining the format, without mentioning that it is a subset of HDF5.

Comment: It is not there any more

Comment: @Mour_Ka the linked PDF still opens for me.

Comment: sorry I meant the Matlab Engine for Python. Here is the new link if I am not mistaken https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from `scipy.io.loadmat` for v4 (Level 1.0), v6, v7 to 7.2 matfiles and  `h5py.File` for 7.3 format matfiles, there is anther type of matfiles in **text data format** instead of binary, usually created by **Octave**, which [can't even be read in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/140081-loading-mat-files-in-matlab-created-from-octave).

Both of `scipy.io.loadmat` and `h5py.File` can't load them (tested on scipy 1.5.3 and h5py 3.1.0), and the only solution I found is `numpy.loadtxt`.

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.loadtxt('xxx.mat')
```

Comment: At least for `.mat` files generated with MATLAB, this will result in a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: @emilaz This is expected. `np.loadtxt` is only meant for `.mat` files generated by Octave.

Comment: Yes, I just put it there as clarification for future people looking at this :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Install scipy

   `pip install scipy`
2. Import the scipy.io.loadmat module

```
     from scipy.io import loadmat
      annots = loadmat('annotation_0001.mat')
      print(annots)
```

3. Parse the .mat file structure

```
   con_list = [[element for element in upperElement] for upperElement in annots['obj_contour']]
```

4. Use Pandas dataframes to work with the data

```
import pandas as pd
   newData = list(zip(con_list[0], con_list[1]))
   columns = ['obj_contour_x', 'obj_contour_y']
   df = pd.DataFrame(newData, columns=columns)
```

refrence:
https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/mat-files-in-python

Comment: This is already well covered in the accepted answer, and others. Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 2):

Can also use the hdf5storage library. official documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/hdf5storage/information.html#matlab-mat-v7-3-file-support) for details on matlab version support.

```
import hdf5storage

label_file = "./LabelTrain.mat"
out = hdf5storage.loadmat(label_file) 

print(type(out)) # <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: hdf5storage uses scipy in the background

Answer (score 1):

```
from os.path import dirname, join as pjoin
import scipy.io as sio
data_dir = pjoin(dirname(sio.__file__), 'matlab', 'tests', 'data')
mat_fname = pjoin(data_dir, 'testdouble_7.4_GLNX86.mat')
mat_contents = sio.loadmat(mat_fname)
```

You can use above code to read the default saved .mat file in Python.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this problem myself and trying other libraries (I have to say mat4py is a good one as well but with a few limitations) I have built this library ("[matdata2py](https://pypi.org/project/matdata2py/)") that can handle most variable types and most importantly for me the "string" type. The .mat file needs to be saved in the -V7.3 version. I hope this can be useful for the community.

### Installation:

```
pip install matdata2py
```

### How to use this lib:

```
import matdata2py as mtp
```

### To load the Matlab data file:

```
Variables_output = mtp.loadmatfile(file_Name, StructsExportLikeMatlab = True, ExportVar2PyEnv = False)
print(Variables_output.keys()) # with ExportVar2PyEnv = False the variables are as elements of the Variables_output dictionary.
```

with ExportVar2PyEnv = True you can see each variable separately as python variables with the same name as saved in the Mat file.

### Flag descriptions

StructsExportLikeMatlab = True/False structures are exported in dictionary format (False) or dot-based format similar to Matlab (True)

ExportVar2PyEnv = True/False export all variables in a single dictionary (True) or as separate individual variables into the python environment (False)

Answer (score 0):

scipy will work perfectly to load the .mat files.
And we can use the get() function to convert it to a numpy array.

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('point05m_matrix.mat')

x = mat.get("matrix")
print(type(x))
print(len(x))

plt.imshow(x, extent=[0,60,0,55], aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

### To Upload and Read mat files in python

1. Install mat4py in python.On successful installation we get:
2. Successfully installed mat4py-0.5.0.
3. Importing loadmat from mat4py.
4. Save file actual location inside a variable.
5. Load mat file format to a data value using python
   `pip install mat4py`
   `from mat4py import loadmat`
   `boston = r"E:\Downloads\boston.mat"`
   `data = loadmat(boston, meta=False)`