# Write an load multiple biadjacency_matrix using Networkx

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have trouble reading and writing my bipartite graphs as sparse matrix in python. I want to read a mat file back in python but I have trouble going back to a graph, because the mat file gives a numpy.ndarray type file and I need a sparse matrix to reconstruct my graph. Any idea how to make my code work? I think it has to do with loadmat 'object' specification but I don't understand how to go further...

```
import setuptools
import math
from networkx.utils import powerlaw_sequence
from networkx import *
import networkx as nx
from scipy import sparse, io # 
G= nx.Graph()
stockGraph = []
G =bipartite.configuration_model([1, 1], [1, 1], create_using=None, seed=None)
stockGraph.append(G) # stock new graph
G =bipartite.configuration_model([0, 1], [1, 0], create_using=None, seed=None)
stockGraph.append(G) # stock new graph 

graphToMatlab=[]  #then export all my graphs as biadjacency matrix
n=2
for i in range(n):
       myGraphToMatlab=bipartite.biadjacency_matrix(stockGraph[i], row_order=bipartite.sets(stockGraph[i])[0], column_order=bipartite.sets(stockGraph[i])[1], weight='weight', format='csr')  
       graphToMatlab.append(myGraphToMatlab) # stacks adjacency matrix.
io.savemat('manygraphs.mat', dict(graphToMatlab=graphToMatlab)) # save all matrices

mat_contents=io.loadmat('manygraphs.mat', mdict=None, appendmat=True) # then open biadjacency matrices : where the problem lies !!
mat1 = mat_contents['graphToMatlab']
m1=mat1[0,0] # remove the object part WITH THIS LINE, IT WORKS !!
bipartite.from_biadjacency_matrix(mat1[1], create_using=None, edge_attribute='weight')# recreate the first graph
```

I get this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 in from_biadjacency_matrix 
 n, m = A.shape
 AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: Oh, simple !! I found the answer in [How to access fields in a struct imported from a .mat file using loadmat in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984714/how-to-access-fields-in-a-struct-imported-from-a-mat-file-using-loadmat-in-pyth) ! my np arrays all ended with 'type=object ', which provided them from being used a sparse array in "from_biadjacency_matrix" ! So before the last line, I only need to add: m1=mat1[0,0] # remove the object part, and I can get my graph !