# scipy.io.loadmat reads MATLAB (R2016a) structs incorrectly

Tags: python, matlab

Instead of loading a MATLAB struct as a dict (as described in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html and other related questions), scipy.io.loadmat is loading it as a strange ndarray, where the values are an array of arrays, and the field names are taken to be the dtype. Minimal example:

(MATLAB):

```
>> a = struct('b',0)

a = 

    b: 0

>> save('simple_struct.mat','a')
```

(Python):

```
In[1]:
import scipy.io as sio
matfile = sio.loadmat('simple_struct.mat')
a = matfile['a']
a

Out[1]:
array([[([[0]],)]], 
      dtype=[('b', 'O')])
```

This problem persists in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Did you actually read the [MATLAB structs section](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html#matlab-structs) in the documentation link you used above?  It looks like this is all expected behavior....  It goes on to describe how you can use the `squeeze_me` and `struct_as_record` parameters.

Comment: Not closely enough! Thanks. I guess between this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984714/how-to-access-fields-in-a-struct-imported-from-a-mat-file-using-loadmat-in-pyth) and now, structs_as_record has become True by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.  Numpy is just showing you have MATLAB is storing your data under-the-hood.

MATLAB structs are 2+D cell arrays where one dimension is mapped to a sequence of strings.  In Numpy, this same data structure is called a "record array", and the dtype is used to store the name.  And since MATLAB matrices must be at least 2D, the `0` you stored in MATLAB is really a 2D matrix with dimensions `(1, 1)`.

So what you are seeing in the `scipy.io.loadmat` is how MATLAB is storing your data (minus the dtype bit, MATLAB doesn't have such a thing).    Specifically, it is a 2D `[1, 1]` array (that is what Numpy calls cell arrays), where one dimension is mapped to a string, containing a `[1, 1]` 2D array.  MATLAB hides some of these details from you, but numpy doesn't.