# Is there any way to read MATLAB's .mat files in Perl?

Tags: perl, matlab, file-io, mat-file

I have some data generated in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) that I want to process using Perl.  I saved the data from  MATLAB in a .mat file.  Is there any way to read it in Perl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to save the binary MAT file as ASCII from inside MATLAB using something like:

```
load('test_data.mat');
save('test_data.asc', 'var1', 'var2', '-ascii');
```

Then you would have ASCII data to process in Perl.

If you need a solution completely written in Perl, then you should be able to automate the process using the [Math::MATLAB](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Matlab) package on CPAN.

NOTE: If Python is an option, you could use the [`loadmat`](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.io.mio.html#loadmat) function in the [SciPy Python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461).

Answer (score 1):

The Java library [JMatIO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmatio/) has worked well for me. Maybe you can try using [inline Java](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/11/07/java.html).

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, except I don't know Java at all :-(