# Python library to use .mat files

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, import, python-import

I have a .mat file that contains a matrix.

---

The idea is to use a python library (on anaconda) that given the .mat file can extract that matrix and let me use it for further calculation in the python program.

---

Do you know any library that can help me do that and how to use it?

UPDATE: I tried Scipy but i can seem to make it work :(

Comment: Based on the answers to [how to open .mat file without using MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25810678/1609514) it doesn't seem like there is a good way at the moment.

Comment: Although I just noticed in the comments to the question it says try this: [scipy.io.loadmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)

Comment: You'll have to include more information on why it doesn't work