# Reading a Matlab's cell array saved as a v7.3 .mat file with H5py

Tags: python, matlab, h5py

I saved a cell array as a .mat file in Matlab as follows:

```
test = {'hello'; 'world!'};
save('data.mat', 'test', '-v7.3')
```

How can I import it as the list of strings in Python with H5py?

I tried

```
f = h5py.File('data.mat', 'r')
print f.get('test')
print f.get('test')[0]
```

This prints out:

```
<HDF5 dataset "test": shape (1, 2), type "|O8">
[<HDF5 object reference> <HDF5 object reference>]
```

How can I dereference it to get the list of strings `['hello', 'world!']` in Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writing in Matlab:

```
test = {'Hello', 'world!'; 'Good', 'morning'; 'See', 'you!'};
save('data.mat', 'test', '-v7.3') % v7.3 so that it is readable by h5py
```

[image]

Reading in Python (works for any number or rows or columns, but assumes that each cell is a string):

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

data = []
with h5py.File("data.mat") as f:
    for column in f['test']:
        row_data = []
        for row_number in range(len(column)):            
            row_data.append(''.join(map(unichr, f[column[row_number]][:])))   
        data.append(row_data)

print data
print np.transpose(data)
```

Output:

```
[[u'Hello', u'Good', u'See'], [u'world!', u'morning', u'you!']]

[[u'Hello' u'world!']
 [u'Good' u'morning']
 [u'See' u'you!']]
```

Comment: ugly... is there a nicer solution in pandas\python\scipy?

Comment: Scipy doesn't touch v7.3. No idea about pandas.

Answer (score 7):

This answer should be seen as an **addition** to Franck Dernoncourt's answer, which totally suffices for all cell arrays that contain 'flat' data (for mat files of version 7.3 and probably above).

I encountered a case where I had **nested data** (e.g. 1 row of cell arrays inside a named cell array). I managed to get my hands on the data by doing the following:

```
# assumption:
# idx_of_interest specifies the index of the cell array we are interested in
# (at the second level)

with h5py.File(file_name) as f:
    data_of_interest_reference = f['cell_array_name'][idx_of_interest, 0]
    data_of_interest = f[data_of_interest_reference]
```

Reason this works for nested data:
If you look at the type of the dataset you want to retrieve at a deeper level, it says '*h5py.h5r.Reference*'. In order to actually retrieve the data the reference points to, you need to **provide that reference to the file object**.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question. But I found a package to scratch that itch:

[hdf5storage](https://github.com/frejanordsiek/hdf5storage)

It can be installed by pip and works nicely on python 3.6 for both pre and post 7.3 matlab files. For older files it calls `scipy.io.loadmat` according to the docs.

Comment: Could you share the code you use to load the array of string?