# Convert .mat file to any other format such as .txt or .plist

Tags: c, matlab

How to  read data store in a .Mat file and convert it to any other format such as .txt or .plist with a C language project?

If there is already an opensource project that does it, please tell me.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: What is the format of the mat file?  If you open it up in a text edit, how is the data formatted?

Comment: I'm not going to flag this question, but in general, asking for a library recommendation is not suited for SO.

Comment: Don't you think it would have been very helpful to mention that *.mat* files are *MATLAB* files in your question? Or do you really believe that this is a well known fact to everyone on SO? Also adding a MATLAB tag wouldn't have been such a bad idea, wouldn't it? Especially if such a tag already exists, and it does (fixed that for you).

Comment: hey dont take it with me, and this rep system in my point of view sukcs (<--- did that intentionally). I have just a question, there may be bad questions, but when someone ask a question , he asks because he don't know the answer to it, so to whoever know it , may seems as a stupid question. And yes i dont know all possible tags.. -.-

Comment: like each time a person makes his question, what he actually gets is the dose of critics and observation on how he did the question. I think i must bare with it. Thats the nature of ppl nowadays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is doable, see the spec here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/custom-applications-to-read-and-write-mat-files.html?s_tid=doc_12b

in python it is all neatly wrapped up in scipy, see [Read .mat files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/874461/2536029)