# Read Matlab's .mat file in C

Tags: c, matlab

I am using Matlab to generate a large matrix, and I want to use it in C.

How can I read Matlab's .mat file in C?

If it is possible, please answer how?

Comment: May be just simple text parsing ?

Comment: will you please answer in detail, I am new in C.Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean *.m or *.mat files? These are different kinds of monsters you see

Comment: Aren't .m files used for matlab source code?

Comment: @interjay - yes they are, thus my question

Comment: Then your question doesn't make sense. Source code is not the same as a matrix. .m files are read and executed by matlab itself.

Comment: try writing the matrix in Matlab in a text mode (`save -ascii` or `dlmwrite` etc.) then you can read it as a simple text file in C.

Comment: are you trying to read the source code file (.m) or the .mat file?  If .m -- what's the point of doing that .. just type it in a normal .txt file and read it

Comment: oh SOrry,Surely its .mat

Comment: The thing is, we're not here to do your work for you, and what you're asking for is an awful lot of information. You need to learn C, then learn about dynamic memory, file IO, string parsing and then you need to know what the format of the Matlab file is.

Comment: It's all extensively documented.  You might start reading at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html

Answer (score 3):

Supposedly Matlab provides its own API to access such files from C: 
[Read and write MAT files](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html). I haven't used it myself, so I don't know how straightforward this is.

If you really want to access the binary data, a search engine came up with this PDF file, [matfile_format.pdf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf), which describes the entire format. This is definitely not an easy solution.

You can easily read such files in Python however, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python) topic. Reading a file this way and writing it again in a format that's easy for you to use in C seems like a good solution.

Comment: For accessing data without MATLAB API you should take a look at [MATIO](https://github.com/tbeu/matio). Its an open source library for C with support for file versions 4,5 and 7.1.

Comment: Reading and writing such files in Python is a good way to understand what is needed to then access the file in C.  It's a good first step.

Answer (score 1):

**matOpen (C)**

*C Syntax*

```
#include "mat.h"
MATFile *matOpen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
```

**filename**
Name of file to open.

**mode**
File opening mode.

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matopen.html) there are examples and explanations.
[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html) there are all the link for MAT-file API.
I recommend to read and study the examples.

Answer (score -2):

If just text is enough...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *pf;

    pf = fopen("something.m", "r");

    int buffer;

    while (buffer != EOF)
    {

        buffer = getc(pf);
        printf("%c", buffer);

    }



}
```

Comment: This won't read a matrix. It will just output garbage characters to the screen. (Note that the question is actually about .mat files, not .m files as it originally said).

Comment: A solution can be (1)  to make your script generate a readable text file matrix.csv and (2) read the text file with something similar to the solution here proposed. I know that the question is about the .mat file. However other solution and other point of view for the same problem I think are welcome or, at least, should have been discussed