# How to read matlab array in python using h5py

Tags: python, h5py

i have a matlab array > 2GB ...
i want to read it using h5py. The data is a simple 3D double array.
But i simply couldn't find a clue on the internet.

Can someone help me ?
I just need an example, how it's done. The h5py documentation couldn't help me.

Comment: Someone answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python) (see second answer)

Comment: But it doesn't work for me : print data results to 'None'

Comment: Ok, got it. I didn't use option 'r' and overwrote the file with nothing :S Now it works ! Thanks !

Comment: I'll answer anyway, as the other question specifies ".mat" files

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered before, but refering to `.mat` files. As @vikrantt said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19340117/263162) -I'm copying his example code,- recent versions of Matlab save to HDF5 format and those you can just:

```
import numpy as np, h5py 
f = h5py.File('somefile.mat','r') 
data = f.get('data/variable1') # Get a certain dataset
data = np.array(data)
```

Note that this is covered in `h5py`'s own documentation about it's [high level API](http://www.h5py.org/docs/high). I'd recommend reading *Group Objects* to understand better how to extract information from the file, and then *Numpy Compatibility*

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using dictionary syntax:

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('somefile.mat','r')
myvar = f['myvar'].value
```

To load all values look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29856030/1615523