# HDF5 dataset from MATLAB to Pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, hdf5, data-science-experience

I have .mat files with HDF5 data and I want to load it into Python (Pandas DataFrame).  I can load the file:

```
f2 = h5py.File("file.mat")
f2['data']
```

which is an HDF5 dataset:

`<HDF5 dataset "data": shape (9999999, 32), type "<f8">`

If I read it with Pandas:

```
g = pd.read_hdf("file.mat",'data')
```

I get the following error:

`cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed`

How do I convert this to a Pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't read HDF5 files using Pandas methods, that have NOT been written using Pandas.

You can read them using one of the following approaches:

[read matlab v7.3 file into python list of numpy arrays via h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670149/read-matlab-v7-3-file-into-python-list-of-numpy-arrays-via-h5py)

[Reading ALL variables in a .mat file with python h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852481/reading-all-variables-in-a-mat-file-with-python-h5py)

http://poquitopicante.blogspot.de/2014/05/loading-matlab-mat-file-into-pandas.html

[Read .mat files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python)

Comment: I suppose knowing it can't be done is the answer I'll have to settle for.  I'll probably go the numpy array route.  Thanks for the info.