# Accessing Data from .mat (version 8.1) structure in Python

Tags: python, arrays, database, matlab

I have a Matlab (.mat, version >7.3) file that contains a structure (data) that itself contains many fields.  Each field is a single column array.  Each field represents an individual sensor and the array is the time series data.  I am trying to open this file in Python to do some more analysis.   I am using PyTables to read the data in:

```
import tables
impdat = tables.openFile('data_file.mat')
```

This reads the file in and I can enter the fileObject and get the names of each field by using:

```
impdat.root.data.__members__
```

This prints a list of the fields:

> ['rdg', 'freqlabels', 'freqbinsctr',... ]

Now, what I would like is a method to take each field in data and make a python variable (perhaps dictionary) with the field name as the key (if it is a dictionary) and the corresponding array as its value.  I can see the size of the array by doing, for example:

```
impdat.root.data.rdg
```

which returns this:

```
/data/rdg (EArray(1, 1286920), zlib(3))
atom := Int32Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)
maindim := 0
flavor := 'numpy'
byteorder := 'little'
chunkshape := (1, 16290)
```

My question is how do I access some of the data stored in that large array (1, 1286920).  How can I read that array into another Python variable (list, dictionary, numpy array, etc.)?  Any thoughts or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a working solution.  It is not very elegant as it requires an eval.  So I first create a new variable (alldata) to the data I want to access, and then I create an empty dictionary datastruct, then I loop over all the members of data and assign the arrays to the appropriate key in the dictionary:

```
alldata = impdat.root.data
datastruct = {}
for names in impdat.rood.data.__members___:
    datastruct[names] = eval('alldata.' + names + '[0][:]')
```

The '[0]' could be superfluous depending on the structure of the data trying to access.  In my case the data is stored in an array of an array and I just want the first one.  If you come up with a better solution please feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate your code. I get an error when trying to open the file which I made in 8.0 using tables.

How about if you took the variables within the structure and saved them to a new mat file which only contains a collection of variables. This would make it much easier to deal with and this has already been answered quite eloquently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python).

Which states that mat files which are arrays are simply hdf5 files which can be read with:

```
import numpy as np, h5py 
f = h5py.File('somefile.mat','r') 
data = f.get('data/variable1') 
data = np.array(data) # For converting to numpy array
```

Not sure the size of the data set you're working with. If it's large I'm sure I could come up with a script to pull the fields out of the structures. I did find [this tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33262-get-structure-field-names-in-recursive-manner) which may be helpful. It recursively gets all of the structure field names.

Comment: That is what I looked into originally.  The problem is in the fine print: scipy.io.loadmat does not support .mat files created by version 8.1.  The highest version of matlab supported is 7.3.  See notes at the bottom of this page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

Comment: just to be sure, have you tried using it? I have used it with mat files from version 7.14 and 8.0 and not had trouble. They were not structures though.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply.  Yeah, I tried using it.  Didn't work. Probably a problem with the structures.