# Read .mat files in python whose content is a table

Tags: python, scipy, mat-file

I was wondering whether I can read in Python a .mat file that contains a Table, is that possible?

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python), but not much is mentioned there.

So far I have tried to read my .mat that contains the table in this way

```
import tables
from scipy.io import loadmat
from scipy.io import whosmat

x = loadmat('CurrentProto.mat')

print(x)
```

but I cannot address the elements there, I get this with the command `print(x)`

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Mon Jul 29 09:47:17 2019', '__version__': '1.0', '__globals__': [], 'None': MatlabOpaque([(b'CurrentProto', b'MCOS', b'table', array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32))],
             dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')]), '__function_workspace__': array([[ 0,  1, 73, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8)}
```

Is there a way of reading my table in the .mat file or I have to sabe it in a different format within Matlab?

Comment: The `MatlabOpaque` tells us that this a MATLAB object/class that `loadmat` can't translate into a `numpy` equivalent.  It can handle matrices, cells, and struct, the older basic MATLAB structures.

Comment: Python `tables` probably isn't going to help you.  `pandas` uses it to save to `HDF5` files, but it uses its own layout.  So even if you use the MATLAB HDF5 save method, there's no guarantee that the two table layouts will be the same.  `h5py` is `numpy` compatible package for loading HDF5.

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853840/load-matlab-tables-in-python-using-scipy-io-loadmat