# h5py: Issues to correctly read a 'table' class stored in MATLAB (.mat -7.3)

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, hdf5

I am trying to import a MATLAB (.mat -7.3) file in Python 3.8 using the h5py module. The file contains a *structure* class and *table* class. I successfully imported the *structure* class object. However, the *table* class is showing wrong dimensions after importing.

```
    import h5py
    
    Path='data/LUT_0/LUT_0.mat' #path file path to be read
    f = h5py.File(Path, mode='r') #read mat file

    list(f.keys())
```

Results in:

```
['#refs#', '#subsystem#', 'LUT_Refl', 'LUT_Var']
```

LUT_Var is a <HDF5 dataset "LUT_Var": shape(1,6), type"">. Trying to access the data results in:

```
f['LUT_Var'][()]

array([[3707764736,          2,          1,          1,          1,
                 1]], dtype=uint32)
```

However, I am expecting a table of the size: 169560x12. When I export this table as a txt file from MATLAB, I can import is just fine in Python. I can also re-import the .mat file in MATLAB and don´t see any corruption of the data. Does anyone know what could be missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: MATLAB's h5 library version is so obsolete that one can not even obtain it. I suggest using [`scypy.io.loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) .

Comment: Thanks, Ander. I tried that. "The following error was raised: NotImplementedError: Please use HDF reader for matlab v7.3 files" This led me to other posts here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316880/reading-v-7-3-mat-file-in-python But I never managed to solve my problem. Again, importing the structure part of the .mat worked well.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. By the way, I get the same *exact* array as you with my table data (`array([[3707764736, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint32`) despite having a completely different table. This must be a header Matlab uses in the HDF5 format to signify a table. The contents of that table seem to be lost in h5py though.

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853840/load-matlab-tables-in-python-using-scipy-io-loadmat

Answer (score 1):

@ThatNewGuy. I could access the contents of the Matlab file this way:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

f = h5py.File(matloc, 'r') # matloc = path to your .mat
print(list(f))

re = f.get('LUT_Refl/Full')
w = f.get('LUT_Refl/WL')

data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(re)).transpose()  # For converting to a NumPy array
wl = pd.DataFrame(np.array(w))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in the general case. See also https://github.com/skjerns/mat7.3/issues/32