# Read table variable in a Matlab V7.3 file with python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a `.mat` file (`V7.3` format) from other people with a structure and a table variable inside. With the common python package (`hdf5storage` and `h5py`), I can load the structure in this `.mat` file, but the content in the table is shown as a strange integer vector

```
[3707764736 2 1 1 110 1]
```

I tried the codes in

[h5py: Issues to correctly read a 'table' class stored in MATLAB (.mat -7.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136526/h5py-issues-to-correctly-read-a-table-class-stored-in-matlab-mat-7-3)

but it gives the same strange vector.

Does anyone have the experience on this issue? Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a really common problem without any good answers I'm afraid. Aside from what you've already tried, perhaps try `mat73` package, https://pypi.org/project/mat73/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried `mat73`, and it gave error message as below.                                            ERROR:root:ERROR: MATLAB type not supported: table, (uint32)

Comment: Sorry I can't help further but if you do find a solution please do come back and answer your own question. I'm sure it will be very helpful to lots of people.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will come back when there is a solution.

Comment: Hello @FelixLiang, did you ever solve this issue? I have encountered the same MATLAB type not supported error.

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853840/load-matlab-tables-in-python-using-scipy-io-loadmat