# How to import .mat files into Jupyter notebook to use them for machine learning in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, matlab, import, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have around 700 .mat files saved in my PC (64-bit, Windows 8 OS), and these files contain matlab structures containing matrices, and other information about them like eigenvalues etc. I produced these files by running some matlab codes.

Now, I'm newly learning scikit-learn, and I'd like to import the .mat files onto my Jupyter notebook, and would like to perform machine learning in scikit-learn (not in matlab) on the matrices saved in the above mentioned .mat files.

1. How can I do this import onto Jupyter?
2. Also, the matrices above are probably saved in matlab array format. How can I transform them into numpy arrays to make them ready for scikit-learn use?

I'm very new to Jupyter and Python in general, so I'd greatly appreciate a step by step instruction if you could.

Answer (score -2):

As long as I know you should convert everything to python (read: do all the work all over again) but Jupyter should support also R-notebooks. 
So if you just want to have a notebook you can convert your data from matlab to R (see: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-March/158144.html) and then create it.

Hope it could be useful, if not I am sorry.
Best luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry I don't know R at all, and would like to do the ML in Python only.

Is there a way to convert a .mat file into a Python file to use it into Jupyter?

Comment: Maybe it could be a stupid anwer from me because you probably already googled it but isn't this working?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python