# Simulate neural network from mat-file in Python

Tags: python, neural-network

How can I simulate neural network in mat-file in Python? Help me, please.

Comment: what do you mean by that? what is a *mat-file*? do you want to run a simulation inside the file (but I am not sure I understand what could that mean)? or you have some representation of the neural network in the file? in that case what do you mean by simulate the neural network?

Comment: I have a neural network in file .mat that I made in matlab. I would like to simulate that neural network in python

Comment: Typically MATLAB files can be read in Python. Its content will likely be just a matrix. Whatever you do with that will depend on what the matrix represents.

Comment: Can you give me an example of reading matlab network from .mat by python? if its not hard for you

Comment: See [loadmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html#scipy.io.loadmat). Make sure to read the notes below - there are also HDF5 libraries for Python if your Matlab version is sufficiently recent.

Comment: @KonstantinPenzev I am afraid you are getting a bit over the lines. Googling `read matlab file python` gives plenty of results like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python this would solve the *reading* part. As for the *simulation* part you are on your own until you provide some more information on what the content of the file is. There is an indefinitely large number of possible implementation of a Neural Network and your question will not lead you anywhere in its current form. Additionally, *simulation* here might be MATLAB jargoon in need of clarification.