# Load .mat file in python

Tags: python, spyder, shortcut, file-read, mat-file

I am working with on a course by coursera, and wanted to try the scripts locally.
I got this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets/data.mat'
```

The file is in the directory and I can see it from Finder on MAC, however, it's not visible form the file explorer in Spyder.

I found this question: [Read .mat files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/874461/6203203)
and checked that original module according to what is suggested in the first answer, but still the file cannot be reached.

I don't know if it's worth mentioning, but the file has a shortcut icon (even though I've downloaded it directly from coursera).

Why the file is not reachable? and how reach it?

Comment: It sounds like a filepath issue, not a problem with the file itself. Try printing your 'datasets/' directory from within Python using `os.listdir()` and see if your .mat file shows up.

Comment: @berkelem Thanks for your comment. However, I already thought of the filepath problem, and the `os.listdir() ` returns the files in the path including the one of my interest. 
Actually, I also tried to access the file through the `Atom` editor, but it's not accessible from there either.