# Import data tables in Python

Tags: python, matlab, data-science

I am new to Python, coming from MATLAB. In MATLAB, I used to create a [variable table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuDfV.png) (copy from excel to MATLAB) in MATLAB and save it as a .mat file and whenever I needed the data from the MATLAB, I used to import it using:

```
A = importdata('Filename.mat');
```

[Filename is 38x5 table, see the attached photo]

Is there a way I can do this in Python? I have to work with about 35 such tables and loading everytime from excel is not the best way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read .mat files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("your_data.csv")
dataframe.head() # prints out first rows of your data
```

Or from Excel:

```
dataframe = pd.read_excel('your_excel_sheet.xlsx')
```

Comment: As far as I am concerned the excel import is called with  pd.Excelfile('your_excel_sheet.xlsx') ... https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial

Comment: Is there not an easy way like in MATLAB where I can just copy tables from excel to python and save it as a .py file

Answer (score 0):

In order to import excel tables into your python environment you have to install pandas.
Check out the detailed [guideline](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial).

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile('myFile.xlsx')
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am 99% sure that there is no simpler way in Python, but pls correct me if I am wrong