# I have a folder containing files in .mat format. Is there a way I can convert all those files to json using python?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm doing a project on segmentation of brain MRI scans and only have .mat files for dataset which I want to read in python and keep the annotations in those files the same.Can somebody help me?

I've tried using mat4py but no success.

This data is organized in matlab data format (.mat file). Each file stores a struct
containing fields for an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the .mat files using scipy:

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('mri.mat')
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html).
Be aware that the method [doesn't support matlab v7.3 files](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) but a solution is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19340117/3284713)