# How to split 'matfile' (which has 4 elements)? I want to save each element into separate list

Tags: python, image, mat-file

I am trying to split 4 elements in 'xxx.mat' file and want to store each element into a separate list.
In other words, I want (100,100) data and save into other list
and then, I want to make image file (.bmp) by using that data (100,100).

xxx.mat file includes

```
type       size 
list         0
bytes        1
string       1
float64  (100,100)
```

I have tried

```
a = np.genfromtxt('xxx.mat', delimiter=',')
```

However, I have got the result as

```
[[nan nan ....... nan nan]
 [nan nan ....... nan nan]
```

I tried to compare the data by using the following code (I have converted MAT-file to CSV file)

```
mat_contents = sio.loadmat('xxx.mat')
a= np.genfromtxt('xxx.csv', delimiter=',')
```

```
[[nan nan ....... nan nan]
 [nan nan ....... nan nan]
```

Comment: What's a `matfile` please? I think you have omitted a significant tag. What is `sio.loadmat()` please? I think you need to be clearer what you are talking about and what you are trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share with you the solution i came up with:

1. I created a .mat file from random data in matlab and saved it.

```matlab
X = rand(100,100)
save("xxx.mat","X")
```

2. Using `scipy.io`and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python) i loaded the .mat file into my python workspace

```py
import scipy.io

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('xxx.mat')
X = mat["X"]
```

3. Using the `PIL`library to convert the data to a black and white .bmp

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.fromarray(X, 'L')
img.save('my.bmp')
img.show()
```

[image]