# How can I save my array into a matlab struct in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mat-file

I have loaded some struct (called `sensor`) into python from my Matlab by doing this

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
pathToData="C:\Projects\"
fileName = "\sensor.mat"
pathToData = pathToData + fileName
matfile = loadmat(pathToData, squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=False)
sensor = matfile['sensor']
```

I can read the data properly but now I would like to write into it some results from python. THe struct has already the field `gDist`, but I cannot write onto them, why is that?

```
vmag_in = sensor.vmag_mv[0:sampleN]
vphs_in = sensor.vphs_mv[0:sampleN]
k = 0
for v_mag,v_phs in zip(vmag_in,vphs_in):
    gDist= functionA(v_mag, v_phs,sensor.content[k])

    sensor.gDist[k] = gDist # <-This seems not working?

    # Iterate counter
    k = k +1
```

Comment: Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52466911/1534017) help?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "not working" means? For us it is also impossible to reproduce the error, how does `sensor` look like? What is `functionA` doing etc... Please provide more details, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: I can load a simple `struct` as you do and modify field values.  So without further information on your error, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

matlab struct array start from 1 
ther for the Iterate counter
    k = k +1
most be in the first for loop line