# Wrong values when importing Matlab struct into python using scipy.io loadmat

Tags: python, matlab, struct, scipy

I have a Matlab file containing a 750x1 double struct. All cells contain the number "18"

I load this file in Python, using:

```
loadmat(file_name, squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=False)
```

To my surprise, all cells in the resulting numpy.ndarray contain the number "19" (dtype int)

I have tried to set `mat_dtype=True`, but the only difference is the resulting type. The import is still cells containing "19" instead of "18".

Anyone has a clue why this roundup/increment is happening?

Comment: I am not into matlab and python, but check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python there is an alternativ way to load the file

Comment: sorry, this is unrelated to my problem.

Comment: did you try to load it with numpy or pandas?

Comment: `scipy.io.loadmat` loads the mat file and converts the structs to numpy ndarray.

Comment: The mapping from a MATLAB `struct` to numpy array(s) can be confusing (layers of object dtype arrays, etc), but it shouldn't change the values of elements.  But without a sample file, and/or some code we can't help.  With MATLAB code I may be able to generate a .mat with `octave`, and try loading that.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with scipy or loadmat, turns out I was a moron who didn't notice that I was assigning a different struct to the variable (which turned out to be filled with 19s).

Problem embarrassingly solved...