# How to save big mat files in MATLAB with version newer than v7.3 and read it in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a big matrix in MATLAB, which I need to save it in order to use it in python. However, when I save it, MATLAB can't save it except with `-v7.3` but that file version can't be read in Python using the following:

```
import scipy.io as spio
Data = spio.loadmat('example_file.mat', squeeze_me=True)
A = Data[‘B’]
```

So it’s required to read that data using `h5py`, as below:

```
import h5py 
Data = h5py.File(‘example_file.mat’. ‘r’)
A = Data[‘B’]
```

In that way of using `h5py`, the matrix `A` can be read and shown with an extension of H5 and I can’t see the matrix numbers as the file A resulted from the first way (which is using `import scipy.io as spio`) .

Is it possible to save a big matrix from MATLAB in similar way to saving a small matrix and then read it in Python using `import scipy.io as spio`?

Or the other option, is it possible to read a big matrix saved in MATLAB with `–v7.3` in Python and read  the matrix with same extension using `import scipy.io as spio`

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what happens when saving the matrix in format 7.3

In MATLAB, we can generate the matrix and save it in version -v7.3:

```
example = randn(16,200) + i*randn(16,200); 
save('example.mat', '-v7.3')
```

I saved it here in v7.3 because if the matrix is very big, I can't save it except in that version !!

Then, to read that file in python, we must use the `h5py` as below:

```
import h5py as h5 
data_try = hs.File('example.mat', 'r')
A = np.array(data_try )
```

First, the matrix `A`  is not of size of `(16,200)` in python!! it's of size `(200,16)`
Second, when I used for example the matrix `A` as an input of neural network, it shows an error of `"can't cast from structure to non-structure, except if the structure only has a single field python"`.  I think that is because the dtype of matrix `A` in python is something like that `[('real','<f8'), ('imag','<f8')]`. !!

all that is different when saving the matrix from matlab in version newer than v7.3 and then be able to read it using the `import scipy.io as spio` which gives us all simply a matrix of dtype : complex

Comment: What is the problem using `h5py`? Since MAT is now HDF5, there is no purpose in using MATLAB specific libraries.

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python

Comment: @Daniel The problem of using h5py I can't read the files as numpy.

Comment: That is really odd, with the larger size the data must appear from somewhere. Could you provide an example? Does it happen if you just save x=rand(16,200) to a mat file?

Comment: @Daniel I gave an example in the question, and tried explained the issue more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the big matrix in MATLAB using -v7.3 and then to read it in python, process these steps:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5 

data_try = h5.File('example.mat', 'r')
A = np.array(data_try) 
A = A.view(np.complex)  or 
A = A.view(np.complex128)
```

That will enable you to use the resulted output A without that error. 
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

For one matrix save it into binary file:

```
clear
SomeData = 1:100*300;
MyMatrix=reshape(SomeData,100,[]);
disp(class(MyMatrix)) % you must know the data type in python. maybe save this info in file name.

MyMatrixBytes=typecast(MyMatrix(:),'uint8');

fid=fopen('z:/MyMatrixBytes.bin','wb');
fwrite(fid,MyMatrixBytes);
fclose(fid);
```

And in python:

```
import numpy as np

# dtype: double->float64 , single->float32
MyMatrixBytes = np.fromfile("z:/MyMatrixBytes.bin",dtype='float64')
```

Comment: it shows this error: Error using typecast
The first input argument must be a full, non-complex numeric value.  . .   second I need to save it as mat file, ... the bin file can be used in python as an array ?

Comment: Your array is complex? If so then separate real and imag values and save them. this is a simple matlab procedure. Any in python i gave you one line code to convert the bin file to array