# Reading -mat FIles into Python with Matlab 2020

Tags: python, matlab, simulink, mat

I have to read a .mat File into Python. The mat-File includes a 1x1 timeseries from Simulink and I want to have the data in Python. Can anyone please help me.
I use the actuall verison of Matlab so scipy.io is not an opportunity!

Comment: There seem to be a number of options from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python, have you tried all of them?

Comment: Actually yes. I found this post too but nothing didnt works well...

Comment: Please post an example of your .mat file so that we can try and reproduce the error you are having, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: The .mat File is an Output of an Simulink Harness Test Simulation. The name is Sink2.mat and includes the SImulation Data of Output 2 of the Stimulink Model. I took a screenshot in Matlab with the data of this .mat File : 

https://ibb.co/xmK1cMW

My dream would be to read this Data into Python.