# Extract lists from deep array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of `*.mat` files and I can read them easily as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874488/8665962). Each file is in shape `(1,1)` and it look like the following:

```
[[(array([[  20913,   28913,   36913,   44913,   52914,   60914]], dtype=int32), array([[ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1]], dtype=int16))]]
```

In this case, how can I extract each array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reproducing the same nested list you have, it's become easy to understand:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[20913, 28913, 36913, 44913, 52914, 60914]], dtype=np.int32)
arr2 = np.array([[1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.int16)

lst = [[arr1, arr2]]
print(lst)
```

The above is your `lst` structure, also `arr1` and `arr2` are (1,1) :

```
nested1 = lst[0][0].tolist()[0]
nested2 = lst[0][1].tolist()[0]

print(nested1)
print(nested2)
```

first `[0]` to get the `[arr1, arr2]`. Next bracket is for `arr1` and `arr2` respectfully.

with `tolist()` you can convert them to python's built-in list type and because they are (1,1) you need the first item which means `[0]`.