# How to read a .mat file table of contents?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matlab, mat-file

I have a Matlab `.mat` file for table of contents and I want to extract it using Python.

I am using `scipy.io.loadmat` but the data is not being extracted. It shows `None` and `matlabopaqe,mcos`.

I have uploaded the [`.mat` file here](https://github.com/magaalakshmi/mahalakshmi).

```py
import scipy.io 
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy 

matdata = scipy.io.loadmat('matfile.mat')

print(matdata.keys())
print(matdata.items())
```

Comment: Do you have the control over generated files?

Comment: what *is* actually in there, i.e. how did you generate your .mat files?

Comment: You can refer to the answer here
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19340117)

Comment: Could not reproduce the problem here. The file name in the code is different from the one in the GitHub repository, though. In your code you are using `matfile.mat` and in the repository you have `matfle.mat`.

Answer (score 0):

Your matfle.mat is properly readable via this code. Can't reproduce the problem here. Below is the data that got displayed on console

```
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'None', 
'__function_workspace__'])
dict_items([('__header__', b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: 
Fri Feb 25 11:47:02 2022'), ('__version__', '1.0'), ('__globals__', []), ('None', MatlabOpaque([(b'patients', b'MCOS', b'table', array([[3707764736],
   [         2],
   [         1],
   [         1],
   [         1],
   [         2]], dtype=uint32))],
         dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')])), 
('__function_workspace__', array([[ 0,  1, 73, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8))])
```