# read .mat file from folder in same directory in Python

Tags: python, import, directory, structure, mat

I have the following file structure:

```
dir
|______folder
|      |___file1
|      |___file2...
|
|____script
```

So script and folder are in the same directory and all the files in folder are .mat files. I just want to import every .mat file in folder into script. I have tried tons of other strategies but for some reason it doesn't like the way I have things set up. Any and all input is appreciated!

Comment: How do you want to import the .mat files, like do you want to read them as text files? or execute code within them?

Comment: You can open the files as ```with open("folder\file1.mat") as f:       data = readmat(f)```

Comment: You will have to define readmat() by yourself based on your specifications. Check out this question: [Read .mat files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python)