# matlab to python conversion (sub2ind and array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab

I am trying  to convert the following matlab code to pyhton :

```
the dimension for the variable ind is :
```

ind=1x211420 double ; the matrix in python  looks like this : [[962 962 962 962 962 962....]]

```
How can i write the eIm1=Im[ind] syntax to resolve the error. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: matlab (x,y) indexing selects a block, and needs `sub2ind` to get its 'diagonal'.  Numpy [x,y] selects the 'diagonal', and needs reshaping (possibly with the help `np.ix_`) to select the 'block'

Comment: `ravel_multi_index` also acts like `sub2ind`.  Beware of the 1-n versus 0-n-1 indexing difference between the languages.

Comment: @hpaulj, is it possible to provide an example for np.ix. also,Thank you for warning me for indexing.

Comment: I'll have to first run your matlab on a computer with Octave to remind myself of what it's doing.  My matlab memory is stale.

Comment: @maya Can you please respond my answer? I would like to know if my answer solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues, and the subject is confusing...

Start by fixing the input matrices - for testing the values should cover larger range (especially the indices):

```matlab
Im = rand(961, 220)*100; % Scale by 100 for testing
x0 = rand(961, 220)*200+1; % Scale X indices by 200 (range about [1, 202])
y0 = rand(961, 220)*900+1; % Scale Y indices by 900 (range about [1, 902])
```

---

We better save the input in order to use the same input in MATLAB and in Python:

```matlab
if exist('input_data.mat', 'file')
    load('input_data.mat');
else
    % Create random data only if data.mat not exist
    Im = rand(961, 220)*100; % Scale by 100 for testing
    x0 = rand(961, 220)*200+1; % Scale X indices by 200 (range about [1, 202])
    y0 = rand(961, 220)*900+1; % Scale Y indices by 900 (range about [1, 902])
    save('input_data.mat', 'Im', 'x0', 'y0', '-v7'); % Save the data to be used as input to Python
end
```

---

The arguments ordering of `sub2ind` function is `y`, `x`:

Replace `eIm1 = Im(sub2ind(size(Im), floor(re_x0'+1), floor(re_y0'+1)));` with:

```matlab
eIm1 = Im(sub2ind(size(Im), floor(re_y0'+1), floor(re_x0'+1)));
```

Note:
This part is just for following the conventions (make things less confusing).

---

In the Python code, read the `input_data.mat` to NumPy arrays, and reshape:

```python
input_data = scipy.io.loadmat('input_data.mat')  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python
Im = input_data['Im']
x0 = input_data['x0']
y0 = input_data['y0']

[a1, b1] = x0.shape  # [a1, b1] = size(x0);
re_x0 = x0.reshape(a1 * b1, 1)  # re_x0 = reshape(x0, a1*b1, 1);
re_y0 = y0.reshape(a1 * b1, 1)  # re_y0 = reshape(y0, a1*b1, 1);
```

---

When using `np.ravel_multi_index`, it is recommended to use NumPy conventions row-major (C-style).
Using NumPy conventions in Python seems appropriate, because we are using NumPy.

- Remove `order='F'`
- Use `dims=(b1, a1)` - the first dimension applies the X (horizontal) axis, and the second dimension applies Y (vertical) axis.

```python
ind = np.ravel_multi_index((np.int64(np.floor(re_x0.T + 1))-1, np.int64(np.floor(re_y0.T + 1))-1), dims=(b1, a1))
```

---

We can't use linear indexing `eIm1 = Im[ind]` in Python.
We have to represent the 2D array as "long" 1D array.
We may use `ravel()` method: `eIm1 = Im.ravel()[ind]`.

Since MATLAB array is transposed (`eIm1'`): `Im1 = reshape(eIm1', size(Im));`, we also have to transpose `Im` before `ravel()`:

```python
eIm1 = Im.T.ravel()[ind]

Im1 = eIm1.reshape(a1, b1)  # Reshape eIm1 to 2D array
```

---

Comparing Python output with MATLAB output:

```python
output_data = scipy.io.loadmat('output_data.mat')
Im1_matlab = output_data['Im1']

assert np.array_equal(Im1_matlab, Im1)  # The output arrays are exactly equal
```

---

Updated MATLAB code:

```matlab
if exist('input_data.mat', 'file')
    load('input_data.mat');
else
    % Create random data only if data.mat not exist
    Im = rand(961, 220)*100; % Scale by 100 for testing
    x0 = rand(961, 220)*200+1; % Scale X indices by 200 (range about [1, 202])
    y0 = rand(961, 220)*900+1; % Scale Y indices by 900 (range about [1, 902])
    save('input_data.mat', 'Im', 'x0', 'y0', '-v7'); % Save the data to be used as input to Python
end

[a1, b1] = size(x0);
re_x0 = reshape(x0, a1*b1, 1);
re_y0 = reshape(y0, a1*b1, 1);
% eIm1 = Im(sub2ind(size(Im), floor(re_x0'+1), floor(re_y0'+1)));
% The correct order in MATLAB sub2ind is: y, x
eIm1 = Im(sub2ind(size(Im), floor(re_y0'+1), floor(re_x0'+1)));
Im1 = reshape(eIm1', size(Im));

save('output_data.mat', 'Im1', '-v7'); % Save the output to be used as reference for testing in Python
```

---

Updated Python code:

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.io

#Im = np.random.rand(961, 220) + 1
#x0 = np.random.rand(961, 220) + 1
#y0 = np.random.rand(961, 220) + 1

# Read the data from mat file (we want to have the same data as in MATLAB).
input_data = scipy.io.loadmat('input_data.mat')  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python
Im = input_data['Im']
x0 = input_data['x0']
y0 = input_data['y0']

[a1, b1] = x0.shape  # [a1, b1] = size(x0);
re_x0 = x0.reshape(a1 * b1, 1)  # re_x0 = reshape(x0, a1*b1, 1);
re_y0 = y0.reshape(a1 * b1, 1)  # re_y0 = reshape(y0, a1*b1, 1);

# eIm1 = Im(sub2ind(size(Im), floor(re_y0'+1), floor(re_x0'+1)));
#ind = np.ravel_multi_index((np.int64(np.floor(re_x0.T + 1))-1, np.int64(np.floor(re_y0.T + 1))-1), dims=Im.shape, order='F')

# Use dims=(b1, a1) - the first dimension applies the X (horizontal) axis, and the second dimension applies Y (vertical) axis.
# Don't use order='F', because we want the indices in NumPy conventions row-major (C-style).
ind = np.ravel_multi_index((np.int64(np.floor(re_x0.T + 1))-1, np.int64(np.floor(re_y0.T + 1))-1), dims=(b1, a1))

# eIm1 = Im(...);
#eIm1 = Im[ind]
#eIm1 = Im.ravel()[ind]  # Represent Im as 1D array using ravel() method. The elements order is row-major (C-style).
eIm1 = Im.T.ravel()[ind]  # We also have to transpose Im for matching MATLAB eIm1'

# Im1 = reshape(eIm1', size(Im));
Im1 = eIm1.reshape(a1, b1)  # Reshape eIm1 to 2D array


# Compare the result to MATLAB output.
################################################################################
output_data = scipy.io.loadmat('output_data.mat')
Im1_matlab = output_data['Im1']

assert np.array_equal(Im1_matlab, Im1)  # The output arrays are exactly equal
```

Comment: thank you for all the information provided. They are very useful. However, I am 
 still facing some problems with my Python script.

Comment: What kind of problems? Did you try executing my code sample **as is** in MATLAB and Python. The code verifies that the MATLAB and Python results are identical `assert np.array_equal(Im1_matlab, Im1)`.

Comment: Hello Rotem, my problem is with loading .mat file. When i am loading the file with command ans=load('Im2_with_tstart.mat'); it gives me a dimension of 961 by 220 for three different field values(Im,x0,y0).                                                                                   However, when i am using the same.mat file in python using this command data= loadmat('Im2_with_tstart.mat')
Im=data['Im0']                   ; it's giving me a dimension of 2275 by 250.  which is not same as matlab

Comment: Are you saying that you are executing the MATLAB code, and the Python code from my answer, and it's not working? Example: In MATLAB: `Im = rand(961, 220)*100;save('input_data.mat', 'Im', '-v7');`. In Python: `input_data = scipy.io.loadmat('input_data.mat');Im = input_data['Im'];print(Im.shape)`. And the shape is not `(961, 220)`? (Note that the working folder assumed to be the same). What is your version of Python? What is your version of `scipy`? `print(scipy.__version__)` Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: Hello Rotem, I have posted my answer. Thank you so much for your solution it really helped me to get my script working.