# Can MATLAB timetables be imported into Python?

Tags: python, matlab, timetable

I am generating MAT files with timetable variables using Matlab 2021b.  I have never used Python before and want to ensure these MAT files can be easily read into Python as well.  Is importing timetable variables from MATLAB to Python possible?  If not, can Python accept regular table variables?

Thank you!

I have not tried to import the data to Python as I have never used it.  I was hoping a user would know the answer so that we can target our processing and formatting approach.

Comment: Hi! May be it helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python