Running a Python function in MATLAB
I have this python script that contains several functions. I want to run this script in MATLAB and save the outputs Xprw, Yprw, Kprw in MATLAB. I am new to PYTHON and I do not know how to do it. Any suggestion is appreciated
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from stability_test import stabilityTest
from flash_calculation import flashcalculation
from Equation_of_states import PengRobinson, PRW


# SECTION 1: Database
# leave it as it is
# ref_components: this section is to define the components and their properties
# BIC: binary interaction coefficient
# if you want to add new components, please update the ref_components and the BIC table
# format: 'CMP' : [Tc, Pc, Mw, w]
ref_components = {'CO2': [304.2, 7.380, 44.00, 0.2273], 'H2O': [647.3, 22.12, 18.00, 0.3434],
                  'C1': [190.56, 4.599, 16.043, 0.0115], 'nC10': [617.7, 2.110, 142.285, 0.4923]}
BIC = np.array([[0, 0.1896, 0, 0],
                [0.1896, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0.05],
                [0, 0, 0.05, 0]])
BIC_names = list(ref_components.keys())
Kij = pd.DataFrame(BIC, columns=BIC_names, index=BIC_names)


# SECTION 2: Inputs
comps = ['CO2', 'H2O']  # components names as in ref_components
fractions = np.array([0.58, 0.42])  # overall molar fraction
P = 24.45  # pressure in MPa
T = 273.15 + 40  # Temperature in Kelvin
salinity = 0.51  # salinity, unit: molality


# SECTION 3: Stability Test
# NOTE: this section can be ignored for most CO2-Water system in reservoir condition
# To check if the fluid becomes 2-phase under the given P, T conditions or not
#
EOS = PengRobinson
# stability test 1:
# default phase: liquid
# second phase: vapour
mixture = EOS(component_names=comps, composition=fractions, temperature=T, pressure=P, salinity=salinity, phase='AQ',
              ref_components=ref_components, ref_KIJ=Kij)
mixture.get_values()

stabilityTest(mixture=mixture, second_phase='vapour', EOS=EOS, salinity=salinity, phase='NA',
              ref_components=ref_components, ref_KIJ=Kij)

# stability test 2:
# default phase: vapour
# second phase: liquid
mixture = EOS(component_names=comps, composition=fractions, temperature=T, pressure=P, salinity=salinity, phase='NA',
              ref_components=ref_components, ref_KIJ=Kij)
mixture.get_values()

stabilityTest(mixture=mixture, second_phase='liquid', EOS=EOS, salinity=salinity, phase='AQ',
              ref_components=ref_components, ref_KIJ=Kij)

# if either stability test 1 or 2 return a 2-phase output, consider it as 2-phase and do the flash calculation


# SECTION 4: Flash Calculation
# With default PR EOS
Xpr, Ypr, Kpr = flashcalculation(EOS=PengRobinson, comps=comps, fractions=fractions, T=T, P=P, salinity=salinity,
                                 ref_components=ref_components, ref_KIJ=Kij)

# With modified PR EOS: use this one for CO2-Water systems
Xprw, Yprw, Kprw = flashcalculation(EOS=PRW, comps=comps, fractions=fractions, T=T, P=P, salinity=salinity,
                                    ref_components=ref_components, ref_KIJ=Kij)

print('PR EOS:\ncoms: {}\nXpr: {}\nYpr: {}'.format(comps, Xpr, Ypr))

print('\nPRW EOS:\ncoms: {}\nXprw: {}\nYprw: {}'.format(comps, Xprw, Yprw))

I first tried using pyrunfile as:
pyrunfile('main.py')
But I get this error:
Error using > (line 1)
Python Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Do you have numpy installed? Try pip install numpy.

Thanks for your suggestion! I installed all the packages and the code is running successfully!
How can I save the output of the Python code into a .mat file? I mean, instead of the output being printed, I want the outputs to be saved in MATLAB workspace.

I hope this question would help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python
